# Lattices with trivial coinvariants for finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group. A $\mathbb{Z}G$-lattice is a $\mathbb{Z}G$-module that is (as abelian group) a free abelian group of finite rank.

> **Question:** Is there a finite group $G$ and a $\mathbb{Z}G$-lattice $L \neq 0$ such that the coinvariants $L_G = 0$?

Note: For a $\mathbb{Z}G$-module $M$ the coinvariants $M_G$ are defined as:

$$M_G := H_0(G,M) = M/IM = \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}G}M$$
where $I = \langle g-1 \mid g \in G\rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}G$ is the augmentation ideal.

What I know is that if $G$ is a $p$-group, then there is no such lattice. For, for $\bar{L} := L/pL$ the surjection $L \twoheadrightarrow \bar{L}$ induces $L_G = L/IL \twoheadrightarrow \bar{L}/I\bar{L} = \bar{L}/\bar{I}\bar{L}$ where $\bar{I}$ is the augmentation ideal of $\mathbb{F}_pG$ and since $G$ is a $p$-group, $\bar{I}$ is also the Jacobson ideal. So, if $L_G=0$, then $\bar{L}=\bar{I}\bar{L}$ and by Nakayama's lemma, $\bar{L}=0$. But because $L$ is torsion-free, $L=0$ follows.

Comment: Take a matrix $A$ of order 6 in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. Then $A-1\in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, so $A$ makes $\mathbf{Z}^2$ a $C_6$-module with zero coinvariant quotient module.

Comment: @YCor: Cool, thank you very much.